# Requests toolbelt multipart uploading file with CSRF fails

Tags: python, django, file-upload, multipart, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload an .ipa file from my DRF backend to a 3rd party app using python Multipart data encoder (http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html). However, I am getting the following error-

> ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))

If I remove the 'rb' attribute, I get the following error instead-

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Could someone please point out what's wrong here? Btw, I decided to use the requests toolbelt since I might upload huge files.

```
from django.views.generic import View

from django.conf import settings
import os
import requests #sudo pip install requests, it's an external library
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder #pip install requests-toolbelt



class upload_binary(generics.GenericAPIView):

def post(self, request, format=None):

    URL = "http://localhost:9020/"
    csrf = requests.get(URL).cookies['csrftoken']

    post_url = "http://localhost:9020/upload/"
    upload_file_name = "SomeApp.ipa"
    media_dir = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    upload_file_path = os.path.join(media_dir, upload_file_name)


    filedata = MultipartEncoder(fields = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf, 'file1': ('file', open(upload_file_path, 'rb'))
    }) 
    headersdict = {'X-CSRFToken': csrf, 'Content-Type': filedata.content_type}
    upload_bin_req = requests.post(post_url, data = filedata,  headers = headersdict)

    return JsonResponse({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question myself, in case people need to know. Apparently, it was the CSRF on the 3rd party app that was causing the issue. I had to update the 3rd party code to allow REST access to me by disabling CSRF for the view in question. I had to import csrf_exempt and decorate the view in question as following-

```
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

    ...
    ...
   @csrf_exempt 
   def the_third_party_view_I_was_calling(request):
```

In case some one knows a better solution to fix this without disabling CSRF, please let me know.